# How to import or require a TS-module into CommonJS file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

For whatever reason, some of my modules have to be `js` files.

I `import` ts module into my `js` file like this:

`resolver.js`:

```
import { Message } from '../../connectors/message';

// console.log('Message: ', Message);

const resolver = {
  Query: {
    sendMessage: (root, args, ctx) => {
      console.log(args, ctx);
      return Message.send('1', 'message');
    }
  }
};

export { resolver };
```

`message.ts`:

```
const Message = {
  send(id, type) {
    return Promise.resolve({
      recipient_id: '123',
      message_id: '122'
    });
  }
};

export { Message };
```

I use `webpack` to and `awesome-typescript-loader` to compile my `.ts` files.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "esnext"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

/* helper function to get into build directory */
var distPath = function(name) {
  if (undefined === name) {
    return path.join('dist');
  }

  return path.join('dist', name);
};

var webpack_opts = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: distPath('main.js'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: ['node_modules', 'src']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        ts: {
          compiler: 'typescript',
          configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
        },
        tslint: {
          emitErrors: true,
          failOnHint: true
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
};

module.exports = webpack_opts;
```

But I got this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Message } from '../../connectors/message';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
```

How to solve this?

-- update v1 --

I try to use it with `require`

```
// import { Message } from '../../connectors/message';

const { Message } = require('../../connectors/message');

console.log('Message: ', Message);

const resolver = {
  Query: {
    sendMessage: (root, args, ctx) => {
      console.log(args, ctx);
      return Message.send('1', 'message');
    }
  }
};

export { resolver };
```

But I still got an error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../connectors/message'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/workplace-adapter-graphql/src/graphql/modules/messages/resolver.js:3:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
```

-- update v2 --

I add `.ts` file extension to path:

```
const { Message } = require('../../connectors/message.ts');
```

still got error:

```
    export { Message };
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
```

**update 3**: add `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/faker": "^4.1.4",
    "@types/jest": "^19.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^7.10.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "ts-jest": "^20.0.6",
    "ts-node": "^3.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
```

Comment: What about just `const Message = require('../../connectors/message')` (instead of `const {Message}`)?

Comment: @JeremyThille got error same with `update v1`

Comment: I can't test this because I don't have an old node version, so I won't write an answer. But i'm pretty sure you just need to compile your js down to something your node version can understand with babel-loader. No need to change your code. (or just update node) https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Comment: How do you know that's an old version? And @novaline actually yes, what's your Node version?

Comment: @JeremyThille node -v `v9.11.1`

Comment: @lukas-reineke See? That's not an old Node version.

Comment: It should work then. Can you share your webpack.config.js and tsconfig.json so I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: @lukas-reineke 
I update my question, please check again.

Comment: Everything looks good. I don't get any errors. Can you add your package.json as well, maybe its a version problem..

Answer (score 13):

your node version doesn't support `import`. use require instead:

```
var Message = require('./path').Message;
```

-- update --
since you are trying to import a `.ts` file, you need to write that in the path. like this: `require('./path.ts');`

Comment: I update the question, please take a look again. thanks.

Comment: @slideshowp2 Did you get the solution or not. I'm having same problem. Please share the solution. thanks

Comment: Adding 'ts' extension worked for me

Answer (score 2):

try using `require('../../connectors/message')`